# Kivy: INVALID PROPERTY NAME

Tags: python-kivy, kivy

Eu criei um programa em Python e Kivy, mas ele só dá erro!

PROGRAMA PYTHON:

```py
kivy.require("1.11.1")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

def Ridget(FloatLayout):
    pass

class aplication(App):
    def build(self):
        return Ridget


window = aplication()
window.run()
```

PROGRAMA KIVY:

```
<Ridget>:
    Button:
        text: 'Hi'
```

MENSAGEM DE ERRO:

```
   1:
```

> > 2:    :

```
   3:        Button:

   4:            text: 'Hi'
```

Invalid property name

Answer (score 0):

a sua primeira função `Ridget` na verdade tem que ser uma classe porque o `<Ridget>` no arquivo `.kv` é uma instância dela.

```py
class Ridget(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

também é uma boa prática deixar o nome da classe iniciando sempre com letra maiúscula, então eu faria a troca de `aplication` pra `Application`, mas isso é só uma sugestão.

enfim, testei o seguinte código aqui e funcionou:

```py
class Ridget(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        return Ridget()

window = Application()
window.run()
```

espero que ajude de alguma forma.

Answer (score 0):

python:

```py
import kivy
kivy.require("1.11.1")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

def Ridget(FloatLayout):
    pass

class Aplication(App):
    def build(self):
        return Ridget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Aplication().run()
```

No arquivo kivy adicione o tipo de extensão no cabeçalho, desta forma: `#:kivy 1.0`, algumas vezes sem isso o kivy não funciona corretamente ou até não reconhece o arquivo.

kv:

```
#:kivy 1.0
<Ridget>:
    Button:
        text:"Hi"
```

Tente desta forma.